# PHP encoding problems

Tags: php, xml, utf-8, simplexml

After a webhook (XML) trigger, I have a PHP code doing the following treatment:

```
$xmlData = fopen('php://input' , 'rb'); 
while (!feof($xmlData)) { $xmlString .= fread($xmlData, 4096); }
fclose($xmlData);

file_put_contents('orders/order' . date('m-d-y') . '-' . time() . '.xml', $xmlString, FILE_APPEND);
```

And I also transfer this info to a database:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);
$address1 = trim($xml->{'billing-address'}->address1);
$sql="INSERT INTO `Customers`(`address1`)
VALUES
('$address1')";
```

My problem is that character is not properly transported for the xml file and the database.

Original statement:
São Paulo

XML file saved on the server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <address1>S&#xE3;o Paulo</address1>
```

Information on database (utf8_general_ci):

SÃ£o Paulo

Everything seems to be proper set to UTF-8 but I still have this character problems.

Comment: I wish I could give you concrete information but this has always caused me problems. Encoding can be from so many places. Be sure to follow suggested answers here, check php encoding in php.ini, check encoding that you're sending to the browser in apache, check the encoding in your database, even checking the encoding on your php file has assist me in resolving encoding-related issues before. Best of luck friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you establish database connection run the query:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8
```

That should help. Also make sure the data coming from your "web hook" is in that format.

Comment: This solved the database side... At end I used this code: $utf = "SET NAMES utf8"; mysql_query($utf,$con);... The XML file was not show proper on Notepad++, but checking it on chrome, it is proper. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the php functions you are using are not intended to manage multibytes string. Try putting

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
```

at the beginning of your php code and have a look to the [Multibyte String Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) page on php.net to understand if you need to change some function in favour of its corresponding multibyte version.

As a last chance you might try to iconv the string before inserting it to the database:

```
$address1 = trim($xml->{'billing-address'}->address1);
$address1 = iconv(iconv_get_encoding($string), "UTF-8", $address1);
```